# How can i get value from url in php codeigniter and want to display result according to that value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php codeigniter . How can i get value from url in codeigniter . Suppose i want to get value 3 from url and according to that value i want to display result by using if else . I am using dropdown so everytime value changes so result should also change .

url -  http://xyz.ca/show/show/getMortgage/value=3

Comment: Use uri_segment() for this.  http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-uri-segment/

Comment: Don't you mean: `http://xyz.ca/show/show/getMortgage/?value=3` or `http://xyz.ca/show/show/getMortgage/value/3` ?

Comment: sorry url is  http://xyz.ca/show/show/getMortgage/?value=3 . How can i get value from url in codeigniter ?

Comment: try   `$this->input->get('value', TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$this->input->get('value');
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#class-reference).